# Counting lines starting with a symbol

Tags: linux

There are many lines containing the `>` symbol in a file. How can I count the total number of `>` symbols in a file? I have tried `sed` and `grep` and it did not work.

Comment: The title says "lines *starting* with a symbol", but the text says "count total number of `>`", which isn't the same (imagine a line like `>>>>>`). Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GNU grep together with `wc`

```
grep -o '>' file.txt | wc -l
```

`grep -o` prints every match on a separate line. `wc` counts the lines.

---

Btw, it's not 100% clear in your question if the `>` can appear only at the start of a line. If you just want to count the lines that start with a `>` you can use the following grep command:

```
grep -c '^[[:space:]]*>' file.txt
```

`^` matches the beginning of the line, `[[:space:]]*` allows for zero ore more space characters in front of the `>`, just in case.